# Running curl command to enable Firebase email enumeration protection gives Google Cloud SDK Error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-sdk

Dear Stack exchange family,

I'm trying to set the enumeration protection on a firebase project, using the following documentation to guide me:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection

I generated the access token successfully, and added it to the curl command listed below:

```
curl -X PATCH -d "{'email_privacy_config':{'enable_improved_email_privacy':"true"}}" \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer GEMERATED ACCESS_TOKEN' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Goog-User-Project: MY PROJECT_ID' \
    "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/MY PROJECT_ID/config?updateMask=email_privacy_config"
```

However when I executed this curl command in Google Cloud SDK I get multiple errors, with examples below. I am assuming SDK is the correct console to execute this command.

I also re-attempted the command with some of the illegal characters removed but still got errors where the code is not a recognised command.

Example list of errors I saw and also attached in the pics

1. curl:(3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
2. '-H:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable proram or batch file.
3. 'Authorization:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable proram or batch file.
4. 'Content-type:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable proram or batch file.

[image] [image]

Can anyone guide me in troubleshooting these errors. What do they mean or how should I reformat my code to prevent errors from occuring?

Appreciated,